# Python 3 Enum, экранирование

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужна реализовать класс `Enum` в Python 3, что-то типо:

```
class Color(Enum):
    #FF0000 = 1
```

Вопрос, как экранировать решетку?

Comment: Как вы планируете его использовать? Вероятно, есть другие средства, позволяющие решить вашу проблему.

Comment: Только если написать внешний препроцессор, иначе никак.

Comment: На мой взгляд это, при любых прочих условиях, прочто чудовищная идея: брать шестнадцатеричную константу и приравнивать её единице. У вас же там явно цвета. Можно ведь дать человеческое имя этой константе (например `RED`)

Comment: Зачем вообще енум, все ключи которого - шестнадцатеричные значения?

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, так сделать нельзя.

Для идентификаторов Python 3 установлены [следующие правила](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers):

```
identifier   ::=  xid_start xid_continue*
id_start     ::=  <all characters in general categories Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, Nl, the underscore, and characters with the Other_ID_Start property>
id_continue  ::=  <all characters in id_start, plus characters in the categories Mn, Mc, Nd, Pc and others with the Other_ID_Continue property>
xid_start    ::=  <all characters in id_start whose NFKC normalization is in "id_start xid_continue*">
xid_continue ::=  <all characters in id_continue whose NFKC normalization is in "id_continue*">
```

Т.е. идентификатор начинается на один из символов списка `id_start` и может продолжаться любыми символами из списка `id_continue`.

Расшифровка категорий символов:

- Lu - [uppercase letters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm)
- Ll - [lowercase letters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ll/list.htm)
- Lt - [titlecase letters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lt/list.htm)
- Lm - [modifier letters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lm/list.htm)
- Lo - [other letters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lo/list.htm)
- Nl - [letter numbers](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nl/list.htm)
- Mn - [nonspacing marks](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mn/list.htm)
- Mc - [spacing combining marks](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mc/list.htm)
- Nd - [decimal numbers](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm)
- Pc - [connector punctuations](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pc/list.htm)
- Other_ID_Start - explicit list of characters in [PropList.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/6.3.0/ucd/PropList.txt) to support backwards compatibility

  ```
  2118          ; Other_ID_Start # Sm       SCRIPT CAPITAL P
  212E          ; Other_ID_Start # So       ESTIMATED SYMBOL
  309B..309C    ; Other_ID_Start # Sk   [2] KATAKANA-HIRAGANA VOICED SOUND MARK..KATAKANA-HIRAGANA SEMI-VOICED SOUND MARK
  ```

Полный список символов перечислен на [этой странице](http://www.dcl.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/home/loewis/table-3131.html).

Так как экранирование символа не входит в определение синтаксиса идентификатора, можно сделать вывод, что оно невозможно в рамках существующей модели синтаксиса.